# LibreOffice Math to LaTeX Extension

Tags: latex, libreoffice

I'm looking for an extension that works with [LibreOffice's Math](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/math/) application where I could create mathematical formulas in the application and then use the extension to export the formulas to LaTeX.

I would like the extension to meet the following requirements:

- Gratis
- Compatible with the latest version of LibreOffice
- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any `.odf` [OpenFormula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFormula) to LaTeX standalone translator or [LibreOffice extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/@@search?SearchableText=latex).

An option would be the [TexMaths](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/texmaths-1) extension to *create the original document mathematical formulas in LaTeX*.  Thus, such a LaTeX expression would be available for other uses without the need for some translation.

Some alternatives to LibreOffice Math for LaTeX Math Editors include:

- [TeX equation editor](http://atomurl.net/math/) online
- Visual Math Editor [online](http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/VisualMathEditor.html) or [downloable for offline use](http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/site/download.html)